# How do I Make a message form in ASP.NET in C# without using a form

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, nested

Ok this is what I have so far. I dont know where to put my email address and its not thowing any errors. it keeps failling the message.

my content.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Contact" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="JeremiahTorresportfoliov1.Contact"%>


<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<hgroup class="title">
    <h2>How to get in touch</h2>
</hgroup>

<section class="contact">
    <header>
        <h3>Phone:</h3>
    </header>
    <p> 
        <span>863.307.1652</span>
    </p>    
</section>
<section class="contact">
    <header>
        <h3>Email:</h3>
    </header>
    <p>
        <span><a href="lostdestany2685@gmail.com">Jeremiah@Leftclique.com</a></span>
    </p>
</section>

<section class="contact">
    <header>
        <h3>Address:</h3>
    </header>
    <p>
        5337 N. Socrum Loop Rd. #208<br />
        Lakeland, FL 33809
    </p>

</section>


<%@ Register Src="~/MyUserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="MyUserControl" %>



<uc1:MyUserControl runat="server" id="MyUserControl" />
</asp:Content>
```

and this is my contact.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace JeremiahTorresportfoliov1
{
public partial class Contact : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

MyUserControl.aspx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="JeremiahTorresportfoliov1.MyUserControl" %>

<div class="focus" >
<label>
    I need...</label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="cboConsultationType" runat="server" CssClass="select sub web">
    <asp:ListItem Value="I Need A New Web Site">A completely new website</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Web Site Upgrade">My website upgraded</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Application Design">An application </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<ul>

    <asp:Label EnableViewState="false" ID="lblErrorMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>

<li>
<asp:Label EnableViewState="false" ID="lblName" AssociatedControlID="txtName" runat="server"
        Text="Name"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation">    </asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"
        ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="Name is required">* </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</li>
<li>
    <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtPhone" EnableViewState="false"
        Text="Phone"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation">  </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorPhone" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"
        ControlToValidate="txtPhone" ErrorMessage="Phone is required">* </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</li>
<li>
    <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtEmail" EnableViewState="false"
        Text="Email"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation">  </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"
        ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="Email is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorEmail" runat="server"
        ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
        ValidationGroup="ContactValidation" ErrorMessage="Email address is invalid">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</li>
<li>
    <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtMsg" EnableViewState="false"
        Text="How can we assist you?"></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Wrap="true"> </asp:TextBox>
</li>
<li>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="submit"
        Text="Send" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
</li>
</ul>
```

MyUserControl.ascx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace JeremiahTorresportfoliov1{
public class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
bool bSent = false;
try
{
    //create the email and add the settings
    var email = new MailMessage();
    email.From = new MailAddress(FromEmail);
    email.To.Add(new MailAddress(FromEmail));
    email.Subject = Subject;
    email.IsBodyHtml = true;



    //send the email
    var smtpServer = new SmtpClient();
    smtpServer.Send(email);

    //mark as sent ok
    bSent = true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //send any errors back
    //add your own custom handling of errors;
}

//let the end user know if it was a success
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + (bSent  ? SuccessText : FailureText) + "');", true);
}

//properties    
public string FromEmail
{
get { return _fromEmail; }
set { _fromEmail = value; }
}
public string Subject
{
get { return _subject; }
set { _subject = value; }
}
public string SuccessText
{
get { return _successText; }
set { _successText = value; }
}
public string FailureText
{
get { return _failureText; }
set { _failureText = value; }
}

//fields
private string _fromEmail = "lostdestany@aol.com";
private string _subject = "Website Enquiry";
private string _successText = "Thank you for submitting your details we will be in touch shortly.";
private string _failureText = "There was a problem submitting your details please try again shortly.";

}


}
```

Comment: Your `Inherits` tag is wrong. What is `JeremiahTorresportfoliov1.Contact`?

Comment: If you want to inherit form Control, it should be usercontrol(ascx), not aspx. Move all your controls to for example, myUserControl.ascx. Add that control in your contact.aspx and fix inheritance in code and markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't inherit a form from a control, it should be from System.Web.UI.Page. Add a usercontrol and move all markup and code to that control:

**MyUserControl.ascx:**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="JeremiahTorresportfoliov1.MyUserControl" %>

<div class="focus" >
    <label>
        I need...</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="cboConsultationType" runat="server" CssClass="select sub web">
        <asp:ListItem Value="I Need A New Web Site">A completely new website</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Web Site Upgrade">My website upgraded</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Application Design">An application </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Other">Other</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
<ul>
    <li>
        <asp:Label EnableViewState="false" ID="lblErrorMessage" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:Label EnableViewState="false" ID="lblName" AssociatedControlID="txtName" runat="server"
            Text="Name"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"
            ControlToValidate="txtName" ErrorMessage="Name is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPhone" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtPhone" EnableViewState="false"
            Text="Phone"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorPhone" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"
            ControlToValidate="txtPhone" ErrorMessage="Phone is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtEmail" EnableViewState="false"
            Text="Email"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation"
            ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ErrorMessage="Email is required">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorEmail" runat="server"
            ControlToValidate="txtEmail" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
            ValidationGroup="ContactValidation" ErrorMessage="Email address is invalid">*</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:Label ID="lblMsg" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtMsg" EnableViewState="false"
            Text="How can we assist you?"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMsg" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" Wrap="true"></asp:TextBox>
    </li>
    <li>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="submit"
            Text="Send" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

**MyUserControl.ascx.cs:**

```
namespace JeremiahTorresportfoliov1
    public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool bSent = false;
    try
    {
        //create the email and add the settings
        var email = new MailMessage();
        email.From = new MailAddress(FromEmail);
        email.To.Add(new MailAddress(FromEmail));
        email.Subject = Subject;
        email.IsBodyHtml = true;

        //build the body
        var sBody = new StringBuilder();
        sBody.Append("<strong>Contact Details</strong><br /><br />");
        sBody.AppendFormat("Needs: {0}<br />", cboConsultationType.SelectedValue);
        sBody.AppendFormat("Name: {0}<br />", txtName.Text);
        sBody.AppendFormat("Email: {0}<br />", txtEmail.Text);
        sBody.AppendFormat("Number: {0}<br />", txtPhone.Text);
        sBody.AppendFormat("Comment: {0}<br />", txtMsg.Text);
        email.Body = sBody.ToString();

        //send the email
        var smtpServer = new SmtpClient();
        smtpServer.Send(email);

        //mark as sent ok
        bSent = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //send any errors back
        //add your own custom handling of errors;
    }

    //let the end user know if it was a success
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + (bSent ? SuccessText : FailureText) + "');", true);
}

//properties    
public string FromEmail
{
    get { return _fromEmail; }
    set { _fromEmail = value; }
}
public string Subject
{
    get { return _subject; }
    set { _subject = value; }
}
public string SuccessText
{
    get { return _successText; }
    set { _successText = value; }
}
public string FailureText
{
    get { return _failureText; }
    set { _failureText = value; }
}

//fields
private string _fromEmail = "info@example.com.au";
private string _subject = "Website Enquiry";
private string _successText = "Thank you for submitting your details we will be in touch shortly.";
private string _failureText = "There was a problem submitting your details please try again shortly.";

}


    }
}
```

Add this control to your page and fix code.

**Contact.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Title="Contact" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="JeremiahTorresportfoliov1.Contact" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/MyUserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="MyUserControl" %>


<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <uc1:MyUserControl runat="server" id="MyUserControl" />
</asp:Content>
```

**Contact.aspx.cs:**

```
namespace JeremiahTorresportfoliov1
{
    public partial class Contact : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I can see in your update you still have error. Change this in MyUserControl.ascx.cs:

```
public class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

to this:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

In Contact.aspx move reference to Myusercontrol to top of the page like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="Contact" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="JeremiahTorresportfoliov1.Contact"%>

<%@ Register Src="~/MyUserControl.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="MyUserControl" %>
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
```

Comment: Im trying to implement your code but I get this error:    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" CssClass="submit"Text="Send" ValidationGroup="ContactValidation" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />                                Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.contact_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btnSubmit_Click' and no extension method 'btnSubmit_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.contact_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Looks like you  still have the button in your contact.aspx page. Please look at the contact.aspx in my answer. This button should be in the control, MyUserCintrol.ascx.

Comment: do you mind if i email you my code. i have tried everything. my email is lostdestany2685@gmail.com

Comment: also how would i put in my email address?

Comment: Paste in body or attach as zip file.

Comment: i made changes @afzalulh

Comment: i made the changes. However, im still getting the error. I put my mailing address at the end of the MyUserControl.acsx.cs. is that wrong?@afzalulh

Comment: No, that is fine. What is the error you are getting now? You can email me details.